# Insert div in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm trying to insert `div` with text to `contenteditable` and select the text between the div tags after adding the div:

```
div.innerHTML +='<div id="id">selecttext</div>'
```

but this won't select the selecttext

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenteditable" contenteditable></div>
        <script>
            var contenteditable = document.getElementById("contenteditable");

            contenteditable.onkeyup = function (e) {
                contenteditable.innerHTML += '<div>Start here</div>';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show some code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: When are you inserting div.innerHTML +='<div id="id">selecttext</div>'? And what is that div?

Comment: i want to select the word "start here" or put the caret between the ned added div

Comment: can you say, what a goal? why `onkeyup`?

Comment: on key down...i just want to insert word between the div and select it like when select with the word the mouse...
and selecting only the word otherwise all the added div will erased when you change the word between the div

Answer (score 0):

Your question has three parts:

> 1. Insert `div` with text to `contenteditable`:

```
contenteditable.innerHTML += '<div id="startHere">Start Here</div>';
```

> 2. Find startHere `div`:

```
function findStartHereDiv(contenteditable) {
    var childNodes = contenteditable.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(childNodes[i].id == 'startHere') {
            return childNodes[i];
            break;
        }
    }
   return null; 
}
```

> 3. Select text of startHere `div`:

```
function selectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Is this what you need?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/boqnkt4k/1/)